# Agora Video call Not showing on my React.js Project

Tags: reactjs, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng, agora-implementation

https://github.com/techwithtim/Agora-Group-Video-Calling
Using this example for implementation of the Agora Video Call . But in this All are working fine but the video is not displaying on the React js Project page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have Setup agora-rtc-react by following this example but the agora video is not visible in my Project but when I have cloned this this Project it is working Properly  . I want to know that this both Project is similar but why video is not visible in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from videocall.js

```
if (tracks) await client.publish([tracks[0], tracks[1]]);
```